# Deploy files to Windows host machine with GitLab Runner

Tags: deployment, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner, cicd

I would like to automatically deploy my Angular application on my Apache server using GitLab CI/CD.

This Apache server is on a Windows Server machine which is itself on a private network.

Here is the `.gitlab-ci.yml` file that I set up:

```
image: node:16.13.1

cache:
  paths:
    - node_modules

stages:
  - setup
  - build
  - deploy

setup:
  stage: setup
  script:
    - npm install

build:
  stage: build
  script: 
    - npm install @angular/cli
    - ./node_modules/.bin/ng build
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - dist

deploy_test:
  stage: deploy
  script:
    - cp -R ./dist/* /my_volume_in_container/
  dependencies:
    - build
  tags:
    - my-test-runner
```

After some research, I saw that the best thing to do would be to run a GitLab runner directly on the host machine. So here is my `config.toml` file:

```
concurrent = 1
check_interval = 0

[session_server]
  session_timeout = 1800

[[runners]]
  name = "Test runner"
  url = "https://gitlab.com/"
  id = 111
  token = "xxx"
  token_obtained_at = 2022-10-13T17:24:15Z
  token_expires_at = 0001-01-01T00:00:00Z
  executor = "docker"
  [runners.custom_build_dir]
  [runners.cache]
    [runners.cache.s3]
    [runners.cache.gcs]
    [runners.cache.azure]
  [runners.docker]
    tls_verify = false
    image = "ubuntu:latest"
    privileged = false
    disable_entrypoint_overwrite = false
    oom_kill_disable = false
    disable_cache = false
    volumes = ["/cache", "/www/my_app/:/my_volume_in_container:rw"]
    shm_size = 0
```

As you can see, I try to pass by a volume to deploy my all files (I don't know if it's the best way) but it does not work at all.

Do you know how I could deploy these files ?